# Selenium driver not able to load all element for some page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I been trying to load https://www.sc.com/sg/atm-branch-locator/ page through selenium + chromedriver + java but it's not load properly in test browser.

Normally its load properly in browser.

```
 public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Downloads\\Selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
         ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://www.sc.com/sg/atm-branch-locator/");
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("ATM"));
       System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

    }

}
```

Is anybody facing a similar issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your usecase is to simply load the page `https://www.sc.com/sg/atm-branch-locator/` you can induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  public class A_demo 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
          options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options); 
          driver.get("https://www.sc.com/sg/atm-branch-locator/");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.m-atm-branch-locator")));
          System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
          driver.quit();

      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <html class="js geolocation inputsearchevent json svg checked template arrow progressbar meter hidden no-touchevents video notification canvas canvastext emoji details supports csstransforms3d opacity bp--landscape grunticon ua-no-touch ua-windows bp--h-large" lang="en-US"><head><style>.gm-style-pbc{transition:opacity ease-in-out;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.45);text-align:center}.gm-style-pbt{font-size:22px;color:white;font-family:Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;position:relative;margin:0;top:50%;-webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);-ms-transform:translateY(-50%);transform:translateY(-50%)}
  </style><style>.gm-style img{max-width: none;}.gm-style {font: 400 11px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;}</style>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
      <meta charset="UTF-8"><iframe src="javascript:void(0)" title="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; border: 0px; display: none;"></iframe><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/linkid.js"></script><script async="" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-MPWTVNC&amp;l=dataLayer"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-P3BPFN7&amp;l=dataLayer"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-PHQV2K"></script><script blzsys="1" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
  function BlzDynamicImageLoader(registeredPollAfterOnload,expectedImageSourceCheck,responsiveScreenWidths,responsiveCell2GMaxWidth,responsiveCell3GMaxWidth,responsiveCell4GMaxWidth,loadDeferral,visibilityBuffer,legacyIOSVisibilityBuffer,imageFormats,skipHidden){var registeredImages=[];var responsiveScreenWidthIndex=-1;var loadComplete=false;var registerHandler=function(element,event,handler){if(undefined!==element.addEventListener){element.addEventListener(event,handler,false);}else{if(undefined!==element.attachEvent){element.attachEvent("on"+event,handler);}}};var unregisterHandler=function(element,event,handler){if(undefined!==element.removeEventListener){element.removeEventListener(event,handler,false);}else{if(undefined!==element.detachEvent){element.detachEvent("on"+event,handler);}}};var getWindowHeight=function(){if(undefined!==self.innerHeight){return self.innerHeight;}else{if(undefined!==document.documentElement&&undefined!==document.documentElement.clientHeight){return document.documentElement.clientHeight;}else{if(undefined!==document.body){return document.body.clientHeight;}}}};var getVerticalScrollPosition=function(){if(undefined!==document.documentElement&&document.documentElement.scrollTop){return document.documentElement.scrollTop;}else{if(undefined!==document.body){return document.body.scrollTop;}}};var isHidden=function(element){return skipHidden&&(element.offsetWidth<=0||element.offsetHeight<=0);};var getVerticalPosition=function(element){if(!element){return 0;}var verticalPosition=element.offsetTop;var parent=element;while(parent=parent.offsetParent){verticalPosition+=parent.offsetTop;}return verticalPosition;};var shouldLoadNow=function(img){switch(loadDeferral){case"onLoad":if(loadComplete){return true;}case"onVisible":return !isHidden(img)&&(getVerticalPosition(img)-getVerticalScrollPosition()-visibilityBuffer)<=getWindowHeight();case"instant":default:return true;}};var determineScreenWidthIndex=function(){var checkConnection=undefined!==navigator.connection&&undefined!=navigator.connection.type;var check2g=checkConnection&&(navigator.connection.type===navigator.connection.CELL_2G)&&-1!==responsiveCell2GMaxWidth;var check3g=checkConnection&&(check2g||navigator.connection.type===navigator.connection.CELL_3G)&&-1!==responsiveCell3GMaxWidth;var check4g=checkConnection&&(check2g||check3g||navigator.connection.type===navigator.connection.CELL_4G)&&-1!==responsiveCell4GMaxWidth;for(responsiveScreenWidthIndex=0;responsiveScreenWidthIndex<responsiveScreenWidths.length;++responsiveScreenWidthIndex){var currentWidth=responsiveScreenWidths[responsiveScreenWidthIndex];if(check2g&&responsiveCell2GMaxWidth<=currentWidth){break;}if(check3g&&responsiveCell3GMaxWidth<=currentWidth){break;}if(check4g&&responsiveCell4GMaxWidth<=currentWidth){break;}if(window.screen.availWidth<=currentWidth){break;}}};var loadImage=function(img,force){if(!img){return;}if(expectedImageSourceCheck&&force!=true){var currentSrc=img.getAttribute("src",true);if(currentSrc==null){currentSrc="";}if(currentSrc!="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAQAICRAEAOw=="){return;}}var source;var finalImage;var responsiveFormats;if(img.getAttribute("data-blzlqsrc")){finalImage=false;source=img.getAttribute("data-blzlqsrc");responsiveFormats=img.getAttribute("data-blzlqmsi");img.removeAttribute("data-blzlqsrc");img.removeAttribute("data-blzlqmsi");}else{finalImage=true;source=img.getAttribute("data-blzsrc");responsiveFormats=img.getAttribute("data-blzmsi");img.removeAttribute("data-blzsrc");img.removeAttribute("data-blzmsi");}if(null!==responsiveFormats&&responsiveFormats.length>responsiveScreenWidthIndex){var srcDotIndex=source.lastIndexOf(".");if(srcDotIndex>-1){source=source.substring(0,srcDotIndex)+"-"+responsiveScreenWidths[responsiveScreenWidthIndex]+"."+imageFormats[responsiveFormats.charAt(responsiveScreenWidthIndex)];}}if(!finalImage){var nextImageLoadHandler=function(){unregisterHandler(img,"load",nextImageLoadHandler);if(loadComplete){loadImage(img,true);}else{var nextImageDeferredLoadHandler=function(){unregisterHandler(window,"load",nextImageDeferredLoadHandler);loadImage(img,true);};registerHandler(window,"load",nextImageDeferredLoadHandler);}};registerHandler(img,"load",nextImageLoadHandler);}img.setAttribute("src",source);};var loadDynamicImages=function(){var deferredImages=[];for(var imageIndex=0;imageIndex<registeredImages.length;++imageIndex){var img=registeredImages[imageIndex];if(shouldLoadNow(img)){loadImage(img);}else{deferredImages.push(img);}}registeredImages=deferredImages;if(("onVisible"===loadDeferral||"onLoad"===loadDeferral)&&(registeredImages.length==0&&loadComplete)){unregisterHandler(window,"resize",loadDynamicImages);unregisterHandler(window,"scroll",loadDynamicImages);}};var registerDynamicImages=function(){registeredImages=[];for(var registeredImageIndex=0;registeredImageIndex<document.images.length;++registeredImageIndex){var img=document.images[registeredImageIndex];if(img.getAttribute("data-blzsrc")){registeredImages.push(img);}}};var repeatedRegisterAndCheck=function(){if(registeredPollAfterOnload||!loadComplete){registerDynamicImages();loadDynamicImages();}if(!loadComplete){setTimeout(repeatedRegisterAndCheck,100);}else{if(registeredPollAfterOnload){setTimeout(repeatedRegisterAndCheck,500);}}};determineScreenWidthIndex();setTimeout(repeatedRegisterAndCheck,100);if("onVisible"===loadDeferral||"onLoad"===loadDeferral){registerHandler(window,"resize",loadDynamicImages);registerHandler(window,"scroll",loadDynamicImages);}registerHandler(window,"load",function(){loadComplete=true;registerDynamicImages();loadDynamicImages();});repeatedRegisterAndCheck();}
  //]]></script><script blzsys="1" type="text/javascript">var aFeoApplied=true;</script><script blzsys="1" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
  BlzDynamicImageLoader(true,true,[128,240,320,480],-1,-1,-1,"onVisible",100,1000,["png","gif","jpg","webp","jxr","bmp","jp2"],true);
  //]]></script>

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
      <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

      <style type="text/css">

          /* NOTE: This styles can't be in a external stylesheet due to browsers bug */
          .no-touchevents .hover-icon-with-gradient-blue-to-green:hover .hover-icon svg path {
              fill: url('#gradient-blue-to-green');
          }
      </style>

      <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.sc.com/sg/atm-branch-locator/"><title>ATM Branch Locator - Standard Chartered Singapore</title>
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//av.sc.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//s.w.org">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com">
  <link href="//www.googletagmanager.com" rel="dns-prefetch" crossorigin="">
  <link href="//www.google-analytics.com" rel="dns-prefetch" crossorigin="">
  <link href="//www.google.com" rel="dns-prefetch" crossorigin="">
  <link href="//stats.g.doubleclick.net" rel="dns-prefetch" crossorigin="">
  <link href="//c.go-mpulse.net" rel="dns-prefetch" crossorigin="">
  <link href="//s.go-mpulse.net" rel="dns-prefetch" crossorigin="">
  <meta name="description" content="Locate your nearest available Standard Chartered ATM">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="videojs-css" href="https://av.sc.com/assets/global/css/vendor.css?ver=9cfcbc3" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="sc_retail-style-css" href="https://av.sc.com/assets/global/css/style-base.min.css?ver=9cfcbc3" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="sc_retail-style-print-css" href="https://av.sc.com/assets/global/css/style-print.min.css?ver=9cfcbc3" type="text/css" media="print">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="sc_retail-style-mobile-css" href="https://av.sc.com/assets/global/css/style-mobile.min.css?ver=9cfcbc3" type="text/css" media="(max-width: 767px)">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="sc_retail-style-tablet-css" href="https://av.sc.com/assets/global/css/style-tablet.min.css?ver=9cfcbc3" type="text/css" media="(min-width: 768px)">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="sc_retail-style-desktop-css" href="https://av.sc.com/assets/global/css/style-desktop.min.css?ver=9cfcbc3" type="text/css" media="(min-width: 1024px)">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="sg-styles-css" href="https://av.sc.com/assets/sg/css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="all">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://av.sc.com/assets/global/js/utils.min.js?ver=9cfcbc3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://av.sc.com/assets/global/js/head.min.js?ver=9cfcbc3"></script>
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Standard Chartered Singapore">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
  <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=367337298">
  <meta name="google-play-app" content="app-id=air.app.scb.breeze.android.main.sg.prod">
  <meta name="title" content="ATM Branch Locator">
  <meta property="og:title" content="ATM Branch Locator">
  <meta property="og:description" content="Locate your nearest available Standard Chartered ATM">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.sc.com/sg/atm-branch-locator/">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="ATM Branch Locator">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="Locate your nearest available Standard Chartered ATM">
              <meta name="sc:country" content="sg">





              <meta name="sc:page-slug" content="atm-branch-locator">

          <meta name="sc:page-has-no-translation" content="">
          <script type="text/javascript">
          var baseURL = "https:\/\/av.sc.com\/assets\/global";
      </script>
      <link href="//av.sc.com/assets/global/fonts/sc-sans-web-regular.woff2" rel="preload" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="//av.sc.com/assets/global/fonts/sc-sans-web-light.woff2" rel="preload" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="//av.sc.com/assets/global/fonts/sc-sans-web-bold.woff2" rel="preload" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="//av.sc.com/assets/global/fonts/sc-sans-web-thin.woff2" rel="preload" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://av.sc.com/sg/content/images/cropped-TrustMark-512px-2-50x50.png" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://av.sc.com/sg/content/images/cropped-TrustMark-512px-2-228x228.png" sizes="192x192">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="https://av.sc.com/sg/content/images/cropped-TrustMark-512px-2-228x228.png">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://av.sc.com/sg/content/images/cropped-TrustMark-512px-2-295x295.png">

    <script>(window.BOOMR_mq=window.BOOMR_mq||[]).push(["addVar",{"rua.upush":"false","rua.cpush":"false","rua.upre":"false","rua.cpre":"false","rua.uprl":"false","rua.cprl":"false","rua.cprf":"false","rua.trans":"SJ-a168f60d-01e4-43e5-964e-392a0f091972","rua.cook":"false","rua.ims":"false","rua.ufprl":"false","rua.cfprl":"true"}]);</script>
    <script>!function(){function o(n,i){if(n&&i)for(var r in i)i.hasOwnProperty(r)&&(void 0===n[r]?n[r]=i[r]:n[r].constructor===Object&&i[r].constructor===Object?o(n[r],i[r]):n[r]=i[r])}try{var n=decodeURIComponent("");if(n.length>0&&window.JSON&&"function"==typeof window.JSON.parse){var i=JSON.parse(n);void 0!==window.BOOMR_config?o(window.BOOMR_config,i):window.BOOMR_config=i}}catch(r){window.console&&"function"==typeof window.console.error&&console.error("mPulse: Could not parse configuration",r)}}();</script>
    <script>!function(e){var a="https://s.go-mpulse.net/boomerang/",t="addEventListener";if("False"=="True")e.BOOMR_config=e.BOOMR_config||{},e.BOOMR_config.PageParams=e.BOOMR_config.PageParams||{},e.BOOMR_config.PageParams.pci=!0,a="https://s2.go-mpulse.net/boomerang/";if(window.BOOMR_API_key="EP972-LG3Q9-XKJ3K-L6EQZ-YHDWK",function(){function n(a){e.BOOMR_onload=a&&a.timeStamp||(new Date).getTime()}if(!e.BOOMR||!e.BOOMR.version&&!e.BOOMR.snippetExecuted){e.BOOMR=e.BOOMR||{},e.BOOMR.snippetExecuted=!0;var i,o,r,_=document.createElement("iframe");if(e[t])e[t]("load",n,!1);else if(e.attachEvent)e.attachEvent("onload",n);_.src="javascript:void(0)",_.title="",_.role="presentation",(_.frameElement||_).style.cssText="width:0;height:0;border:0;display:none;",r=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],r.parentNode.insertBefore(_,r);try{o=_.contentWindow.document}catch(O){i=document.domain,_.src="javascript:var d=document.open();d.domain='"+i+"';void(0);",o=_.contentWindow.document}o.open()._l=function(){var e=this.createElement("script");if(i)this.domain=i;e.id="boomr-if-as",e.src=a+"EP972-LG3Q9-XKJ3K-L6EQZ-YHDWK",BOOMR_lstart=(new Date).getTime(),this.body.appendChild(e)},o.write("<bo"+'dy onload="document._l();">'),o.close()}}(),"".length>0)if(e&&"performance"in e&&e.performance&&"function"==typeof e.performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize)e.performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize();!function(){if(BOOMR=e.BOOMR||{},BOOMR.plugins=BOOMR.plugins||{},!BOOMR.plugins.AK){var a="true"=="true"?1:0,t="",n="3nn6mnaxbhon6xqb2tfq-f-15ef62313-clientnsv4-s.akamaihd.net",i={"ak.v":25,"ak.cp":"267530","ak.ai":parseInt("142112",10),"ak.ol":"0","ak.cr":66,"ak.ipv":4,"ak.proto":"h2","ak.rid":"a34d4ac5","ak.r":15853,"ak.a2":a,"ak.m":"x","ak.n":"essl","ak.bpcip":"219.91.230.0","ak.cport":41043,"ak.gh":"23.57.69.173","ak.quicv":"","ak.tlsv":"tls1.2","ak.0rtt":"","ak.csrc":"-","ak.acc":"","ak.t":"1577178315"};if(""!==t)i["ak.ruds"]=t;var o={i:!1,av:function(a){var t="http.initiator";if(a&&(!a[t]||"spa_hard"===a[t]))i["ak.feo"]=void 0!==e.aFeoApplied?1:0,BOOMR.addVar(i)},rv:function(){var e=["ak.bpcip","ak.cport","ak.cr","ak.csrc","ak.gh","ak.ipv","ak.m","ak.n","ak.ol","ak.proto","ak.quicv","ak.tlsv","ak.0rtt","ak.r","ak.acc","ak.t"];BOOMR.removeVar(e)}};BOOMR.plugins.AK={akVars:i,akDNSPreFetchDomain:n,init:function(){if(!o.i){var e=BOOMR.subscribe;e("before_beacon",o.av,null,null),e("onbeacon",o.rv,null,null),o.i=!0}return this},is_complete:function(){return!0}}}}()}(window);</script>
              <script async="" src="https://ds-aksb-a.akamaihd.net/aksb.min.js"></script><script>var w=window;if(w.performance||w.mozPerformance||w.msPerformance||w.webkitPerformance){var d=document;AKSB=w.AKSB||{},AKSB.q=AKSB.q||[],AKSB.mark=AKSB.mark||function(e,_){AKSB.q.push(["mark",e,_||(new Date).getTime()])},AKSB.measure=AKSB.measure||function(e,_,t){AKSB.q.push(["measure",e,_,t||(new Date).getTime()])},AKSB.done=AKSB.done||function(e){AKSB.q.push(["done",e])},AKSB.mark("firstbyte",(new Date).getTime()),AKSB.prof={custid:"267530",ustr:"",originlat:"0",clientrtt:"66",ghostip:"23.57.69.173",ipv6:false,pct:"10",clientip:"219.91.230.52",requestid:"a34d4ac5",region:"15853",protocol:"h2",blver:14,akM:"x",akN:"ae",akTT:"O",akTX:"1",akTI:"a34d4ac5",ai:"142112",ra:"true",pmgn:"RUMwwwsccom",pmgi:"",pmp:"",qc:""},function(e){var _=d.createElement("script");_.async="async",_.src=e;var t=d.getElementsByTagName("script"),t=t[t.length-1];t.parentNode.insertBefore(_,t)}(("https:"===d.location.protocol?"https:":"http:")+"//ds-aksb-a.akamaihd.net/aksb.min.js")}</script>
              <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/38/11/common.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/38/11/util.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.sc.com%2Fsg%2Fatm-branch-locator%2F&amp;2sgme-standardchartered&amp;callback=_xdc_._f3ov45&amp;client=gme-standardchartered&amp;token=26672"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/38/11/map.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/38/11/marker.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/38/11/onion.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/38/11/stats.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/ViewportInfoService.GetViewportInfo?1m6&amp;1m2&amp;1d1.0313970698784292&amp;2d103.09845110504784&amp;2m2&amp;1d1.6708632532030552&amp;2d104.54240700287755&amp;2u12&amp;4sen-US&amp;5e0&amp;6sm%40496000000&amp;7b0&amp;8e0&amp;callback=_xdc_._6z7b7r&amp;client=gme-standardchartered&amp;token=66475"></script></head>
  <body class="page-template-default page page-id-19595" data-catch="show-overlay">
  <!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://av.sc.com/assets/global/css/modules/meganav/megamenu-ie9.min.css">
  <![endif]-->

  <header class="sc-hdr">
      <div class="sc-hdr__wrapper sc-hdr__container">
      <nav class="sc-hdr__nav">
          <!-- Hamburger Menu: Visible only for mobile -->
          <button class="sc-hdr__btn sc-hdr__hamburger no-desktop">
          <svg width="26" height="21" viewBox="0 0 26 21" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M25.5 11H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h25a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1zm0-10H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h25a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1zM.5 20h25a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1z" fill="#B9B9B9" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
          </svg>
          </button>
          <button class="sc-hdr__btn sc-hdr__close-button no-desktop"><span class="visuallyhidden">Close button</span></button>

          <!-- Navigation Menu Section -->
          <ul class="sc-hdr__list">
          <!-- Home  Menu Icon -->
          <li class="sc-hdr__item no-mobile">
              <a href="https://www.sc.com/sg/" class="sc-hdr__menu sc-hdr__btn home" title="Meganav Links Home"><span><svg width="25" height="20" viewBox="0 0 18 15" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M3 14V6.162L8.948 1.54 15 6.184V15h1V6.952L17.366 8 18 7.186 9 0 0 7.187.634 8 2 6.939V15h13v-1H6V8H5v6H3z" fill="#221F20" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
            </svg></span></a>
          </li>

          <!-- Location Menu -->
          <li class="sc-hdr__item has-meganav category">
              <button class="sc-hdr__btn sc-hdr__back no-desktop"><span class="visuallyhidden">Back button</span></button>
              <button class="sc-hdr__btn sc-hdr__menu location">You're in <span class="highlight segment-loc" style="background:#fff !important;">Singapore</span>
              <span class="icon no-mobile">
            <svg width="7" height="4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-10 13.2 14.7 8.4"><style>.st0{fill:#d5d5d5}</style><path class="st0" d="M4.7 14.6l-7 7H-3l-7-7 1.3-1.4 6 6 6-6 1.4 1.4z"></path></svg>
          </span>

              </button>
              <span class="sc-hdr__menu sectors no-desktop">Segments</span>
              <!-- Location Megamenu section -->
              <div class="sc-hdr__mgnv-wrapper">
              <div class="sc-m-cat sc-mgnv sc-hdr__container">
                  <!-- Location Megamenu Left Section-->
                  <div class="sc-m-cat__left sc-mgnv__left">
          <span class="sc-mgnv__title">
            <span class="no-desktop">Change country: </span>
            <span class="no-mobile">Welcome to <br>Standard Chartered<br></span>
            <span class="sc-m-cat__country">Singapore <svg class="icon-right-arrow" width="4" height="6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-12 12.9 4.6 7.1"><style>.st0{fill:#c0c0c0}</style><g><path class="st0" d="M-12 18.9l2.5-2.5L-12 14l1.1-1.1 3.5 3.5-3.5 3.5z"></path></g></svg></span>
          </span>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Location Megamenu Right section -->
                  <div class="sc-m-cat__right">
                  <a class="sc-m-cat__link" title="Personal Banking" href="https://www.sc.com/sg/personal/">
                      <span class="name">Personal Banking</span>
                      <span class="icon icon-personal-banking" style="background-image: none;"><svg id="ICONS" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 30"><style>.st0,.st1{fill:#c6c6c6}.st1{stroke:#d4d4d4;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:100}</style><path class="st0" d="M1 30c-.6 0-1-.4-1-1v-5.1c0-1.3 1.2-2.7 2.1-3.1l5.7-2.3c.5-.2.7-.4.8-.6.2-.5.8-.7 1.3-.5.5.2.7.8.5 1.3-.4 1-1.4 1.4-1.8 1.6l-.2.1-5.7 2.2c-.2.3-.7 1-.7 1.3V29c0 .5-.4 1-1 1zM23 30c-.6 0-1-.4-1-1v-5.1c0-.4-.4-1.1-.6-1.2l-5.8-2.3c-.5-.2-1.5-.6-2-1.6-.2-.5 0-1.1.5-1.3.5-.2 1.1 0 1.3.5 0 .1.2.2.9.5.1 0 .1.1.2.1l5.6 2.2c.9.3 1.8 1.8 1.8 3.1V29c.1.5-.3 1-.9 1zM13 16h-1.7c-2 0-4-2.2-4.6-5.1v-.1L6 5.7C6 2.5 8.5 0 11.6 0h1.5c2.9.2 5.2 2.7 5.2 5.6v.1l-.7 5C17 13.7 15 16 13 16zm-4.4-5.6c.5 2.2 1.9 3.5 2.7 3.5H13c.8 0 2.2-1.4 2.7-3.5l.6-4.8c0-1.9-1.5-3.4-3.4-3.6h-1.3C9.6 2 8 3.6 8 5.6l.6 4.8zm8.7-4.7z"></path></svg></span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="sc-m-cat__link border-right" title="Business Banking" href="https://www.sc.com/sg/business/">
                      <span class="name">Business Banking</span>
                      <span class="icon icon-business-banking" style="background-image: none;"><svg id="ICONS" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 30"><style>.st0{fill:#c6c6c6}</style><path class="st0" d="M28.6 30H3.4C1.5 30 0 28.5 0 26.6V10.4C0 8.5 1.5 7 3.4 7h25.2c1.9 0 3.4 1.5 3.4 3.4v16.2c0 1.9-1.5 3.4-3.4 3.4zM3.4 9C2.6 9 2 9.6 2 10.4v16.2c0 .8.6 1.4 1.4 1.4h25.2c.8 0 1.4-.6 1.4-1.4V10.4c0-.8-.6-1.4-1.4-1.4H3.4z" id="Rounded_Rectangle_4_11_"></path><path class="st0" d="M22 5c-.6 0-1-.4-1-1v-.8c0-.7-.8-1.2-1.5-1.2h-6.8c-.8 0-1.7.5-1.7 1.2V4c0 .6-.4 1-1 1s-1-.4-1-1v-.8c0-2 1.9-3.2 3.7-3.2h6.8c2 0 3.5 1.4 3.5 3.2V4c0 .6-.4 1-1 1z" id="Rounded_Rectangle_4_10_"></path><path class="st0" d="M4.5 25.5c-.3 0-.5-.2-.5-.5v-9c0-.3.2-.5.5-.5s.5.2.5.5v9c0 .3-.2.5-.5.5z"></path><path class="st0" d="M16.2 21.5c-.5 0-1-.1-1.5-.3L.9 15.7l.7-1.9 13.8 5.4c.5.2 1 .2 1.5 0l13.8-5.4.7 1.9-13.8 5.4c-.4.3-.9.4-1.4.4z"></path></svg></span>
                  </a>
                  <span class="sc-m-cat__link" title="Priority Banking">
            <span class="name sublinks">
                                          <a href="https://www.sc.com/sg/priority/">Priority Banking</a>
                                          <span>
              <a href="https://www.sc.com/sg/priority/priority-private/">Priority Private</a>
                                              <a href="https://www.sc.com/sg/international-banking/">Int'l Banking</a>
                                              <a href="https://www.sc.com/sg/save/savings-accounts/myway/">MyWay</a>
                                              <a href="https://www.sc.com/sg/global-banking/global-citizen/">Global Indian</a>
                                          </span>
                                      </span>
              <span class="icon icon-sc-s-online-rewards" style="background-image: none;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 31.5"><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="ICONS"><path d="M21 23.36H11a4 4 0 0 1-4-4.06V0h18v19.3a4 4 0 0 1-4 4.06zM9 2v17.3a2 2 0 0 0 2 2.05h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2.05V2z" fill="#d4d4d4" id="Rounded_Rectangle_11" data-name="Rounded Rectangle 11"></path><path fill="#d4d4d4" d="M11 18.3h10v1H11z"></path><path d="M8 17.25a1 1 0 0 1-.59-.19 58.43 58.43 0 0 1-5.12-4.17A7.66 7.66 0 0 1 0 7.1 5.17 5.17 0 0 1 5 2h3a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H5a3.15 3.15 0 0 0-3 3.1 5.66 5.66 0 0 0 1.71 4.38 58 58 0 0 0 4.88 4A1 1 0 0 1 8 17.25z" fill="#d4d4d4" id="Shape_28" data-name="Shape 28"></path><path d="M24 17.25a1 1 0 0 1-.59-1.81 58 58 0 0 0 4.88-4A5.66 5.66 0 0 0 30 7.1 3.15 3.15 0 0 0 27 4h-3a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h3a5.17 5.17 0 0 1 5 5.1 7.66 7.66 0 0 1-2.29 5.79 58.43 58.43 0 0 1-5.12 4.17 1 1 0 0 1-.59.19z" fill="#d4d4d4" id="Shape_28_copy" data-name="Shape 28 copy"></path><path d="M16 31.49a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-7.12a1 1 0 0 1 2 0v7.12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1z" fill="#d4d4d4"></path><path fill="#d4d4d4" d="M9 30.5h14v1H9z"></path><path d="M15.94 9.89a2.78 2.78 0 1 1 2.75-2.79 2.77 2.77 0 0 1-2.75 2.79zm0-4.07a1.28 1.28 0 1 0 1.25 1.28 1.27 1.27 0 0 0-1.25-1.28z" fill="#d4d4d4" id="Ellipse_7_copy_4" data-name="Ellipse 7 copy 4"></path></g></g></svg></span>
            </span>
  ```

Comment: Still the issue is there, Page not load properly. the body part load as blank in test browser.

Comment: @MahendraSahu Have you used the same code as I have provided within my answer?

Comment: Yes, But still facing the same issue.

Comment: @MahendraSahu Did you remove `deleteAllCookies()`,  `maximize()`, `implicitlyWait`, `` and `pageLoadTimeout` completely? Can you update the question with your code trials and the output of `getPageSource()`?

Comment: @MahendraSahu Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: i have updated my code with latest one but still facing the same issue for page loading. Encountered with below error

  " Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector: div.m-atm-branch-locator (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)"

Answer (score 0):

ATM menu has an id, try using the ID instead of title contains?
And when the page loads , the last thing that appears on it is the ATM menu.
Try switching driver maybe?
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());